# ToExpression cannot parse MathML in Mathematica Online

Tags: mathematica-online

It seems that only things like `ToExpression["1+1"]` can be evaluated without error in Mathematica Online. Converting `TeXForm`, `TraditionalForm`, and `RowBox` always gives error with result returns:

> FrontEndObject::notavail: A front end is not available; certain operations require a front end
>   and sometimes crashes the kernel.

But when converting `MathMLForm`, any expression (that can be executed on my laptop) would return `$Failed`. I thought `ImportString` could also parse MathML, so I tried

```
CellPrint[
Cell[BoxData[
ImportString["<math><msup><mi>x</mi><mn>2</mn></msup></math>", 
"MathML"]], "Output"]]
```

Sadly it returns red error message(which should be part of the evaluated code)

> BoxData[FormBox[TagBox[x,MathMLPresentationTag,AutoDeleteTrue],TraditionalForm]]

Is there any workaround to parse MathML on Mathematica Online?

Comment: `ToExpression@
 ImportString["<math><msup><mi>x</mi><mn>2</mn></msup></math>", 
  "MathML"]` works for this simple case.  But in general, I had the impression that when pasting MathML, it is often needed to fix up the result before it can be interpreted ...

Comment: @Szabolcs Thank you for your advice. In my mma online, all these commands worked, but when using `CloudEvaluate`, none of these worked. I also see some other person's using mma online and have none of these worked.

Comment: `ToExpression["<math><msup><mi>x</mi><mn>2</mn></msup></math>", MathMLForm]` works in *Mathematica*.  This would seem to be a limitation or bug with the implementation of *Mathematica Online*.  I would suggest contacting tech. support.